# Xamarin: Data Bindings not refreshing when used, but when some code is removed and typed back in it suddenly works

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm currently making an app in Xamarin. I created a list view which I'll be turning into a to-do list. I'm currently having a problem where if I use my [Add],[Remove], or [Edit] buttons on first launch, none of those options no matter what. To make it work, I have to remove the letter [s] from the [Tasks] then put it back in my code after a few seconds:

```
<ListView x:Name="taskNames" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"></ListView>
```

I have no errors, warnings, or any of the like but this problem stumped me. Please watch the recording I did of it to fully understand what's happening: https://youtu.be/Y7UOjsucHpA

Here's my full ToDoPage.xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Health.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Health.Views.ToDoPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ToDoListViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="To Do List" FontSize="Title" TextDecorations="Underline"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Entry Placeholder="Tasks" Text="{Binding TasksToAdd}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Entry>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Padding="10,0,10,0">
                <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddTasksCommand}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Button>
                <Button Text="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveTasksCommand}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
                <Button Text="Edit" Command="{Binding EditTasksCommand}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="End"></Button>
            </Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="taskNames" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then below, I have my ToDoListViewModel.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Health.ViewModels
{
    class ToDoListViewModel
    {
        public ICommand AddTasksCommand => new Command(AddTask);
        public ICommand RemoveTasksCommand => new Command(RemoveTask);
        public ICommand EditTasksCommand => new Command(EditTask);
        public ObservableCollection<string> Tasks { get; set; } 
        public string TasksToAdd { get; set; }

        public string SelectedTask { get; set; }

        public ToDoListViewModel()
        {
            Tasks = new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "Task 1",
                "Task 2",
                "Task 3",
            };
        }
        public void AddTask()
        {
            Tasks.Add(TasksToAdd);
        }

        public void RemoveTask()
        {
            Tasks.Remove(SelectedTask);
        }

        public void EditTask()
        {
            int newIndex = Tasks.IndexOf(SelectedTask);
            Tasks.Remove(SelectedTask);

            Tasks.Add(TasksToAdd);
            int oldIndex = Tasks.IndexOf(TasksToAdd);
            
            Tasks.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then below is my ToDoPage.xaml.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace Health.Views
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class ToDoPage : ContentPage
        {
            public ToDoPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                taskNames.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3" };
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thing I should add is that this ToDoPage.xaml is being referenced to my AppShell for navigating the app's tab bars. I'll have the code for it below too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Health.Views" 
       xmlns:footer="clr-namespace:Health.ViewModels"
       Title="Health"
       x:Class="Health.AppShell">
    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
            <Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png" Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="To Do" Icon="ToDoIcon.png" Route="ToDoPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ToDoPage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Scheduler" Icon="SchedulerIcon.png" Route="SchedulerPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SchedulerPage}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Exercise" Icon="ExerciseIcon.png" Route="ExercisePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ExercisePage}"/>
    </TabBar>
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I'm really not sure why this is working, I hope someone can tell me what's happening because my code has no errors :/

Comment: Instead of setting tasks to new in the ctor, try doing `public ObservableCollection<string> Tasks { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();`, then just add your tasks in the actor.

Comment: I tried but the result is the same as the video, I don't know why it's doing it this way. My code has no errors but it doesn't work unless I do the things above.

Comment: Based on the code you posted ,I did a test. But it works well on my side. Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?